# Problem while change keyboard layout using both Shift

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I updated from 13.04 to 14.04 a few weeks ago.

In 13.04 I was able to change layout pressing <kbd>L_Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R_Shift</kbd> in this way:

If I press <kbd>L_Shift</kbd>, and while pressing it, also press <kbd>R_Shift</kbd> and then release <kbd>R_Shift</kbd> - layout will change.

In 14.04 this is not working:

If I press <kbd>L_Shift</kbd>, and while pressing it, also press <kbd>R_Shift</kbd> and then release <kbd>R_Shift</kbd> - layout will **NOT** change until I also release <kbd>L_Shift</kbd>.

---

In case of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>, this works fine. If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and release - layout will change. It works as in 13.04

How to make Both Shifts behave as in 13.04?

*Sorry if it is not clear, don't know how to explain it*

Comment: I have the same problem after migrating from Debian to Ubuntu 14.04. Have you being able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @DmitriySukharev unfortunately not. Please let me know if you solve problem